# Create jQuery array from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I want to create an associative array in jQuery using the values returned in a JSON object.
The JSON object is dynamically created:

```
[{"name":"key1","value":"value1"},{"name":"key2","value":"value2"},{"name":"key3","value":"value3"},{"name":"key4","value":"value4"}]
```

I want to create an associative array of this format using the values returned in JSON:

```
aResult = {key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2', key3 : 'value3', key4 : 'value4'};
```

Currently when I iterate through the JSON object, I can see the desired array structure in console

```
$.each(jData, function(k, v) {
    if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf("answer") >= 0) {
        name = v.name;
        value = v.value;
        console.log(name + ' : ' + value); //returns the structure I wish
    };

});
```

But when I add this code in the loop to create array

```
var aResult = {name:value}
```

It returns `[object Object]`

What am I missing? How should I go forward? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `aResult={};aResult[name]=value;` or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it

```
var obj = {};
$.each(data, function(i, v){
       obj[v.name] = v.value
   });
console.log(obj)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ygqaa/)

Answer (score 1):

The command jQuery.parseJSON() convert JSON in a Object.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse the json using

```
$.parseJSON();
```

it is required to convert JSON to object
After that try using

```
$.each(data, function(n, val) {
    console.log(name + ': name = ' +val.name + ' value = ' + val.value);
  });
```

Comment: I am already parsing JSON, I am getting the structure in console, I just don't know how to create an array with it.

Comment: Well if you would read my question you'll see am already doing this part.